# how to pass parameters in sqlite transaction in cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have a bookid and i need to pass it on sqlite transaction in cordova
like

```
var bookName  = db.transaction(function(tx){
                    return tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Iqra_Book WHERE book_id=?',[1],function(tx,res){
                        var leng = res.rows.length;
                        console.log("Length: " + leng);
                        return bkName = res.rows.item(0).book_name;
                    }
                , function(e) {
                    return console.log("ERROR: " + e.message);
                });
            });
```

But I am getting this booName as undefined.
Can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to pass a variable to the book id. leave away the "return", you cant just return a value since the web database works asynchrounously

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Iqra_Book WHERE book_id ="'+id+'"',[1],function(tx,res){
```

also, change the line

```
return bkName = res.rows[0].book_name;
```

to

```
return bkName = results.rows.item[0].book_name;
```

and check if it works

Comment: i did as u said. But still issue occurs

Comment: I edited my answer, I also recommend you to read the Storage API Documents of Phonegap documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `values` parameter of the `executeSql()` method.

eg.

```
let id = //the ID of the item you are looking for
tx.execute('SELECT * FROM Iqra_Book WHERE book_id=?',[id])
     .then(queryResult => {
       console.log(queryResult.rows.item(0).book_name)
     }).catch(err => console.error(`ERROR: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
```

**NOTE**

- `item()` is a function - you have that right, it cannot be accessed as an array as is shown in the previous answer (I hate that about the plugin, but that is how it is)
- the values passed in the previous example is just `1`, so I hope the ID you wanted was 1.
- `queryResult.rows` is a list-like object, I would recommend going through a for-loop with the limit of `queryResult.rows.length` unless (like in this case) you know for sure there is only going to be **1** result.